# How do I view PDF attachments to my Google Calendar event synched with my iPhone?

Tags: ios, calendar, pdf, google-calendar, google-sync

I synched my Google Calendar with the iOS Calendar app (iOS 10.3.2) by adding my Google account. I can see the attachments and file size in the event, but when I click on it to view the PDF file, it brings up a gray screen. Multiple attachments to multiple events do not work. I can share or click Done. The attachments work in the desktop web site.

I can see the attachments in the Calendar event on my phone, but when I click on them, it only brings up a blank page without any content. The file size shows in the list of attachments too.

[image] [image]

Comment: If possible, could you please add a screenshot of the blank/gray screen you get?

Comment: Interesting. I just tried this on my phone and it just said there was an error opening the attachment. I'd file this as a bug.

Comment: what is the original source app of the .PDF files ? Try with one that was created by Adobe.

Comment: I don't know. Downloaded from a web site. They work in Safari if I view them from the Google Calendar desktop web site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was, and continues to be, a bug with the way the iPhone calendar app handles Google Calendar attachments. It’s been this way for years.

Answer (score 1):

After testing, the only "solution" (read "work-around") to this at the moment is to upload each attachment to Google Drive and then to add its *raw* link in the Notes section. I say *raw* link, because using the "Link" feature of the Google Calendar app will result in the less-than-pretty HTML code when viewed on iOS, e.g. `<a href="https://drive.asset.blah.blah.blah.pdf">Asset Name</a>`. Thus, the best you can get ATM for fully interoperable compatibility is NOT using either of the Google Calendar features 1) Attachments or 2) Links and instead in the Notes section just providing a short name for the asset followed by the raw Drive link for the asset.

E.g.

NOTES:

Google & Apple's relationship: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1c7A47J0O4wgK1wFBRbEn4Gpc8Ht1XeE2/view?usp=sharing